# Ubuntu 12.04 update to the 3.8 kernel fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I've been trying to update the kernel on our Linux server running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.
Running uname -r displays 2.6.32-042stab113.11 as the current version.
I've run the usual apt-get update to get the latest packages.
I've run the following command:

```
apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-raring linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
```

This outputs the information below with the final lines outputting:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic
linux-image-generic-lts-raring
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Further up the output is another error:

```
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-44-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                           dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-raring:
 linux-image-generic-lts-raring depends on linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic is not configured yet.
```

I've tried running apt-get autoclean, apt-get -f install to fix broken packages.

I am wondering if I could do apt-get remove linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic
linux-image-generic-lts-raring and then install again.

Should I run apt-get upgrade.

I've been reluctant to do this so far in case it breaks the server and puts our sites offline.

Any advice?

Full Output from terminal:

```
root@213-xx-xxx-xx:/var/www/vhosts/example.com# apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-raring linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic-lts-raring is already the newest version.
linux-image-generic-lts-raring is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 176 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic (3.8.0-44.66~precise1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-44-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.8.0-44-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-44-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.8.0-44-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-44-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-44-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-44-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-44-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-44-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                           dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-raring:
 linux-image-generic-lts-raring depends on linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-lts-raring (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-raring
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Ubuntu problem, not a programming problem. Note that this question has already been asked and answered on http://askubuntu.com/questions/302951/update-initramfs-usr-share-initramfs-tools-hooks-fixrtc-failed-with-return-1, which is where this question is on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
```

This should be fixing the problem.

Comment: Thanks Istvan for the suggestion. We use a VPS and it turns out that our server Kernel can't be upgrade due to it sitting on a shared platform.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc
```

as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302951/update-initramfs-usr-share-initramfs-tools-hooks-fixrtc-failed-with-return-1).
This disables the `fixrtc` hook, which is not in all cases needed.
You can undo this step with

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it but it didn't seen to work. uname -r still returns the version I want to upgrade from.I'll try Istvan's suggestion next.

Comment: Try Istvan's solution after mine, especially `dpkg-configure -a`